# Give a subgroup with an identity such that this identity does not hold in the bigger group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

In universal algebra, I am trying to show a counterexample using groups for the converse of "If an identity $s=t$ holds in $\mathcal{L}$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathcal{B}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$, then this identity also holds in $\mathcal{B}$".

My counterexample is the group $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ with subgroup $U(n)=\left \{x\in \mathbb{Z}_{n}:gcd(x,n)=1  \right \}$. The identity $gcd(x,n)=1$ only holds in $U(n)$. Is this a valid counterexample?

Comment: Can $\gcd(x,n)=1$ be expressed in the language of Abelian groups?

Comment: Since when has this $U(n)$ been a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n$? It's not closed under addition.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown My mistake! I will try to find another example that actually makes sense.

Comment: You will not be able to find an example in groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Hello, I was thinking about maybe using the trivial subgroup of the group $\mathbb{M}_{n}$ (set of all $n\times n$ matrices), which is just the identity matrix... Then the commutative identity holds for this subgroup but not in general for $\mathbb{M}_{n}$, right? But wait...$\mathbb{M}_{n}$ is not a group under multiplication...So I can use $GL_{n}$ then?

Comment: But even then you have the wrong direction. You want the identity to fail in the *smaller* one.

Comment: It's not clear to me by what you mean by "an identity."

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh, I see... I thought the converse was "If the identity holds in $\mathcal{B}$, then it holds in $\mathcal{A}$. What is the correct converse?

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that it said "converse". In that case, sure, if the identity is allowed to include a "for all" then this works.

Comment: @Randall Hello, an identity in universal algebra is the expression $\mathbf{s}\dot{=}\mathbf{t}$ where $\mathbf{s,t}$ are $\mathcal{L}$-terms!

Comment: Ah, okay, this is outside my knowledge base then.  Carry on.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for trying to help me though, I understand it a bit more.

Comment: Your idea will actually work with the trivial subgroup of any group, since all identities hold in the trivial group and not in any other group.

Comment: Another simple and less degenerate example could be a free group with two generators and its subgroup generated by one of them: $F(a)\leq F(a,b)$. The subgroup $F(a)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is Abelian, but $F(a,b)$ is not. Being Abelian can be expressed as the identity $x y\approx y x$.

Comment: There is ton of examples really. For instance, you can also take $\{0,2\}\leq \mathbb{Z}_4$. The subgroup satisfies $x+x\approx 0$, but this does not hold in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, since $1+1\neq 0$.